# How can I write my table of data row after row to Excel with xlsxwriter

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, xlsxwriter

I am having issue iterating rows in xlsxwriter once again. I tried many combination of it but failed. Your help will be much appreciated!
My code;

```
file = open("namelist.txt","r")
data = []

for d in file:
    url = "file:///C:/Users/k/Desktop/HTML/"
    t = (url) + d
    data.append(t.strip())
file.close()

# data variable becomes --> ['file:///C:/Users/k/Desktop/HTML/new01.html', 'file:///C:/Users/k/Desktop/HTML/new02.html', 
# 'file:///C:/Users/k/Desktop/HTML/new03.html', 'file:///C:/Users/k/Desktop/HTML/new04.html']

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("namelist.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Name list")

# this peace of code writes header
for headers in data:
    b = data[0]
    browser.get(b)
    header = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/th")
    head = []
    for h in header:
        head.append(h.text)
        worksheet.write_row("A1", head)

print ("Headers written to namelist.xlsx succesfully!")
print ("Given Name list being written to namelist.xlsx...")

# this part of the core overrites the tables to excel file
for i in data:
    browser.get(i)
    trs = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr")
    for n, tr in enumerate(trs):
        row=[td.text for td in tr.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")]
        print (row)
        worksheet.write_row("A{}".format(1+n), row)
print ("namelist.xlsx is ready!")
workbook.close()
```

Each link in data[ ] contain table of different data with the same format. Like this below

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

For loop in my code overwrites the rows so I can only see one of the table above in Excel
[image]

however I need them to be written by iterating to all link and write row after row like this;
[image]

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using worksheet.append instead.

Comment: Instead of worksheet.write_row?

Answer (score 1):

Apperently you have 1,2,3... values in `n` in last loop, make some variable with int and increment it in loop like:

```py
line = 1
for tr in trs:
    row=[td.text for td in tr.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")]
    print (row)
    worksheet.write_row("A{}".format(line + 1), row)
    line += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for the help, It worked out actually however adds space for each loop so there are empty rows in Excel now. I have tried to change; `worksheet.write_row("A{}".format(line), row)`

but didn't work.

[image]

Any idea on how to avoid empty rows for the each loop?